# Change BigQuery Datasource in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I need to Change datasource for bigquery connector in data studio dashboard as i am moving for QA to production environment, schema is same for both of the datasouces.

Is there any way to achieve it so that i don't have to create custom metrics again for new data source.

Answer (score 0):

If the schema is exactly the same I believe you can just edit for data source, choose reconnect and then select the new data source.

Be warned though, this will change that data source for all reports that use it.

Comment: user1 do not have rights to edit data source created by user2. Both QA and production bigquery account are created using different email ids.

Comment: Can edit rights not be given or ownership transferred?

Comment: Edit Rights are given but user can edit report but not datasource, I am not sure how to tranfer ownership

Comment: Datasources can be shared in the same way as reports.

https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/navigation/datasources

Just get the current owner to share the datasource in question and then (if necessary) transfer ownership in the "advanced" options after the new owner has been added.